# Simple TypeError returned with 'undefined' function parameter

Tags: javascript, regex

```
//Validation script
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

const patterns = {
    telephone: /^\d{11}$/
};


function validate (field, regex) { // Here I get a TypeError:  regex is undefined
   if(regex.test(field.value)){
       field.className = 'valid';
   }else{
       field.className = 'invalid';
   }
}

inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('keyup', (h) => {
        //console.log(h.target.attributes.name.value);
        validate(h.target, patterns['h.target.attributes.name.value'])
    });
});
```

---

I receive a TypeError message for 'regex' when I use Console on Web Dev tools.  I'm green when it comes to this and would appreciate any feedback that could help clear up, what I'm assuming, is a simple error.

Comment: `patterns['h.target.attributes.name.value']` will try to fetch the literal key `h.target.attributes.name.value` from the `patterns` object. Since the only key there is `telephone` and it doesn't have `h.target.attributes.name.value`, then it doesn't find it and returns `undefined`. You probably meant to remove the quotes around the key, so it's evaluated `patterns[h.target.attributes.name.value]`

Answer (score 1):

When you call your validate function, the second parameter is evaluating to undefined. I'm guessing you are trying to have it be patterns['telephone']. The key you are looking up in the patterns object is a string when I think you mean for it to be without the quotation marks.

```
patterns[h.target.attributes.name.value]
```

I am assuming h.target.attributes.name.value will evaluate to 'telephone'.